# Is it possible to insert the rsync output inside MySQL database for web page view?

Tags: rsync

I have 5-6 cron jobs running daily.

Is it possible that when rsync runs,  then I can insert the files copies, deleted , size, any errors  and all other stuff inside MySQL database.  So that I can write php script to see the rsync history.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course it's possible. Redirect the output to a file, parse it into fields and values using a script. Then do SQL `INSERT INTO` commands.

Comment: Can everything be done in one step . i mean on rsync command line